# bootstrap - how to display dynamic div inside popover

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm working on Twitter bootstrap 3 and have a question about popover. I have many button in my page with class "details" and i want to use popover for these buttons. but 
popover's content must be different for each button. for this purpose, I have a

```
<div class="details-box" style="display: none;">
   <h1>Dynamic content</h1>
</div>
```

for each button. note content of these divs are dynamic and come from my server. now my question is: how can i use these divs inside popovers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each button, get the text inside `h1` with `text()` function and assign it to `data-content` attribute

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/1504/)

```
var box = $('.details-box');
box.each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var text = that.text();
    that.attr('data-content', text);
    that.popover();
});
```